# Data Protection, Keychain and Core Data's Sqlite files

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, keychain, data-protection

I'd appreciate that someone could make it clear some questions I have regarding `Data Protection` feature:

1. Is needed/recommended to enable `Data Protection` to encrypt and protect the `SQLite` files managed by `Core Data`? If so, what should I do to encrypt and protect such files?
2. I followed a tutorial for using `Keychain` and it said that complete level of `Data Protection` had to be enabled for the App ID in the `Apple Member Center`, so that I did. However, it said nothing about also enabling `Data Protection` in the `Xcode`'s project, so I didn't. It seems that I can access `Keychain` in my iOS app without problem, but this looks weird... should I also enable `Data Protection` in the target's settings?

Thanks so much

Comment: Who are you protecting the data from: The device user or a 3rd party who gains access to the device.

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends what you're storing there and thus what is at risk if someone gains access to it. In most cases you don't need to encrypt the data in the DB specifically as someone will use a device lock to secure the device and any specific data that you want to make secure should be stored in the keychain. This is usually the user identifying data and account authentication tokens.
2. If someone gets access to a device that is unlocked (pin code / touch ID has been cleared or authenticated) then they can do pretty much whatever they want with the device (keychain and automatically encrypted data) and you can't stop them (at best you can slow them down).

   - Apple does mention you can limit access to Keychain data if someone tries to add their fingerprint after-the-fact. More info in the Keychain section of https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

The only thing you can do really is to explicitly encrypt the data which requires it using a key that is explicitly entered by the user each time you need to encrypt / decrypt. That key could be stored in memory temporarily, but you can never write it to disk. In this way the user has to enter the key to use the data and the key can only come from the user.

Comment: Thank you. I'd really like to protect all data in one of my `Core Data`'s data models, since it stores user's sensitive data. So, how could I encrypt the corresponding `SQLite` files? I don't find any tutorial regarding that...

Comment: Even with a google for `encrypt core data sqlite store` ?

Comment: Most likely not. As I said in my answer, it depends exactly what you're trying to achieve. 'true' security will only come from explicit encryption with a user supplied key

Comment: So, what is `Data Protection` useful for? Could you give some guidelines to follow the approach you mention?

Comment: It's a 'simple' way to tie your app into using the device lock (if the user has set a passcode). It tells the OS what and how you want the data to be encrypted (when it should be decrypted).

Comment: @Wain The answer does not answer the question: "*should I also enable Data Protection in the target's settings?*".

Comment: @Wain The answer states: "*any specific data that you want to make secure should be stored in the keychain*" but this is somewhat misleading. While data can be stored in the keychain it should be limited in size and few instances. Data of any substantial size should be encrypted and saved in the fie system with the key in the keychain.

Comment: Fair points @zaph, I'm really trying to broaden the question a bit and say that simply setting the data protection flags may not provide the protection required. Security is a difficult thing and you need to be very clear on what you're trying to achieve for it to be effective.